# jasper reports alternative to poi jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi, docx

I have a Java application that uses Jasper to create docx. Jasper uses poi to export to docx. There are a few issues with the documents generated with poi and I was wondering if there are any good alternatives to poi. Apart from modifying the source code of Jasper, is there a way to link the new jar to Jasper so that it uses it instead of poi? If i write my own docx exporter can it be easily linked so that Jasper will use it? Does anybody know an article that explains how to link a custom jar (or an alternative jar) to Jasper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this post](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/xhtml-import-f28/setuptrpr-not-implemented-t1983.html), it appears the author is converting Jasper's XHTML output into docx format using docx4j.  Perhaps that results in a 'better' docx, without the effort of -rewriting Jasper's docx exporter?

Comment: Thank you Jason. I know about docx4j. So far docx4j seems my best option to try. I'll wait a little bit longer. If I don't get any other suggestions I'll accept your answer.